# Switch text between EditTexts during TranslateAnimation

Tags: android, animation

I have a vertically-oriented LinearLayout (inside a ScrollView) that holds dynamically created Views. Each of these Views contain an EditText. As an option, I would like the user to be able to reorder these Views.

For the reordering, I am providing an UP and a DOWN button. This works great. The animation is smooth and gives the expected output.

**Setup:**

The animation is just a visual feedback: I am *NOT* reordering the Views. I'm only switching the data between two EditTexts. For example:

```
View1 ==== EditText1 ==== TextData1
View2 ==== EditText2 ==== TextData2
```

When the animation ends:

```
View1 ==== EditText1 ==== TextData2
View2 ==== EditText2 ==== TextData1
```

**The Problem:**

I am currently switching the `EditText.getText().toString()` values in `onAnimationEnd(Animation)`. This isn't smooth at all. The best I can do to describe the effect: `flicker`. There's a flicker when the values are switched.

Is there any way to avoid this?

**TranslateAnimation:**

```
static TranslateAnimation translate(float fromX, float toX, float fromY, 
                                                            float toY, int ms) {

    TranslateAnimation transAnim = new TranslateAnimation(fromX, toX, fromY, toY);
    transAnim.setDuration(ms);
    return transAnim;
}
```

How the animation is being applied:

```
// Animate viewToMove to move to viewToReplace's position
TranslateAnimation ta = Utils.translate(0, 0, 0, -viewToReplace.getHeight(), 2000);

// Animate viewToReplace to move to viewToMove's position
TranslateAnimation ta2 = Utils.translate(0, 0, 0, viewToMove.getHeight(), 2000);

// AnimationListener
ta.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        // Grab the text that is held by viewToMove's EditText
        String temp = ((EditText) 
                     (viewToMove.findViewById(R.id.etListItemText))).getText().
                                       toString();

        // Set viewToMove's EditText to show contents of viewToReplace's EditText
        ((EditText) (viewToMove.findViewById(R.id.etListItemText))).
                              setText(((EditText) (viewToReplace.
                                     findViewById(R.id.etListItemText))).
                                                   getText().toString());

        // Set viewToReplace's EditText contents
        ((EditText) (viewToReplace.findViewById(R.id.etListItemText))).
                                     setText(temp);
    }
});

// Start animations
viewToMove.startAnimation(ta);
viewToReplace.startAnimation(ta2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question spiked my curiosity quite a bit, so I setup a dummy project to test what you're trying to do and indeed I saw a flicker.

I managed to solve it by putting the following code in my onAnimationEnd method:

```
String text1 = tb1.getText().toString();
String text2 = tb2.getText().toString();

tb1.setText(text2);
tb2.setText(text1);     

tb1.setAnimation(null);
tb2.setAnimation(null);
```

Setting the animation to null in both EditTexts seems to solve the flickering.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks man, this works fine with a small change: I called `view.setAnimation(null)` _before_ setting the text. Calling it after was still producing the flicker. I'd be grateful if you could explain a bit as to why this works?

Comment: While I'm not absolutely sure, I would say that the Android runtime is clearing and reverting the view's matrix shortly after the onAnimationEnd is called, therefore, the text would change, and an instant later, the view would move back. Setting the animation to null forced the matrix to revert on the spot.

Comment: Also, it's peculiar that the code order here didn't work for you... it worked for me just fine. Strange.

Comment: I see. It makes sense. Not sure why the (minor) modification works. From your explanation, it seems that it particularly shouldn't. Its too late an hour for me to give it another go right now. And, its possible I messed up while testing the two scenarios. In any case, this was very helpful. Thanks again.